# How do I get the version of the source file that I have in my tfs workspace?

Tags: tfs

I want to know what version of a file that I have in my local workspace so that I can revert to the old version if the new version of the file doesn't work.

I cannot seem to find a menu in Visual Studio that gives me the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf localversions <sourceFileName>`

i.e.
`tf localversions MySource.cs`